# Possible bug in VertexWeight implementation in V13.2

Tags: graphs-and-networks, annotationvalue

Is the following a bug in version 13.2.  I am using VertexWeight to track a property of the graph.  I initialize the vertex weights.  Subsequent changes to VertexWeights don't seem to stick.  For examples.

```
gg = EdgeTaggedGraph[{a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a}, VertexWeight -> {1, 1, 1}];
AnnotationValue[{gg, #}, VertexWeight] & /@ VertexList[gg]
gg1 = EdgeTaggedGraph[gg, VertexWeight -> {a -> 2}];
AnnotationValue[{gg1, #}, VertexWeight] & /@ VertexList[gg1]
gg2 = EdgeTaggedGraph[gg1, VertexWeight -> {b -> 2}];
AnnotationValue[{gg2, #}, VertexWeight] & /@ VertexList[gg2]
```

I get

```
{1,1,1}
{2,1,1}
{1,2,1}
```

I was expecting

```
{1,1,1}
{2,1,1}
{2,2,1}
```

What I am missing?  I have a work around by reading out all of the weights, changing selected ones, and then setting all of the weights.  It seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

No, I would not consider this a bug. When you provide an option `VertexWeight -> {a -> 2}`, this is taken as a complete specification for vertex weights, and any previous weights are overwritten with this specification.

You can use [`AnnotationValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnnotationValue.html) to change weights.

```
g1 = Graph[{a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a}, VertexWeight -> {1, 1, 1}];

g2 = g1;
AnnotationValue[{g2, {a, b}}, VertexWeight] = {4, 3};

AnnotationValue[g2, VertexWeight]
(* {4, 3, 1} *)
```